# angular 2 do something after all http calls finished

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I am performing 2 http calls within the angular 2 component. I want to show the success message after these 2 service calls finished. How Can i do that?

```
this._cashierService.postCharge(this.postCharge).subscribe( resPostCharge => {

          this.footerNotification.success('Save', 'Successfully saved'); //i want to show this after 2 calls finished
        }, errorMessage => {

        });

this._cashierService.splitCharge(this.postCharge).subscribe( resPostCharge => {

          this.footerNotification.success('Save', 'Successfully saved');
        }, errorMessage => {

        });
```

Comment: Use the fork-join framework to do this.

Answer (score 0):

chain the observable so that it can call one by one and print the console in the last one. return the second call from first observer subscription.

```
this._cashierService.postCharge(this.postCharge)
    .subscribe(resPostCharge => {

        return this._cashierService.splitCharge(this.postCharge);
    }, errorMessage => {

    })
    .subscribe(resPostCharge => {
        this.footerNotification.success('Save', 'Successfully saved');
    }, errorMessage => {

    });
```

Comment: is this the best way to do that?

Comment: inside call will run after the first call finished. that will lost the asyncronouseness.

Comment: yes. if you have multiple req use the chain mechanism

Comment: @sachila ranawaka no, chain mechanism is not the way to go. Use fork-join to execute the calls in parallel and wait for it to finish before acting on the results.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve that problem using 2 variables:

```js
let firstCallfinished = false;
let secondCallfinished = false;

this._cashierService.postCharge(this.postCharge).subscribe(() => {
  firstCallfinished = true;
  if (secondCallfinished) {
    this.footerNotification.success('Save', 'Successfully saved');
  }
});

this._cashierService.splitCharge(this.postCharge).subscribe(() => {
  secondCallfinished = true;
  if (firstCallfinished) {
    this.footerNotification.success('Save', 'Successfully saved');
  }
});
```